# remove '\t' and '\n' from string

Tags: java

i need to parse html string. i had text like this

```
<html>  <head>      </head>  <body>    <p style="margin-top: 0">      blbibibluboiubiubiu ibiub    </p>  </body></html>
```

i had removed '\n' characters. and now i need to remove '\t' chars. i've tried to do it like this

```
String s = editor.getText();
s = s.replaceAll("\\n", "");
s = s.replaceAll("\\t", "");
```

but it does not work. please help

Comment: You double-escaped your escape sequences. Use a single call with `"[\t\n]"`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: That should work, what makes you think it doesn't? Note, though, that you don't need to use `replaceAll` (which accepts regular expressions), it would be more direct to use `.replace("\n", "")` and `.replace("\t", "")`.

Comment: Are you shure that the whitespaces are tabs and not n blanks?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: `replaceAll` takes a regex, so `\\n` matches newline, `\\t` matches tab...

Comment: @Jens: "sure" (no "h") (as English is your -- very excellently-written -- at least second language).

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/uIbFsZ But again, the `replace` version is more direct: http://ideone.com/6K2QRO

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) or a similar framework if you are to parse HTML. Jsoup can remove newlines and tabs for you in a safe way.

Example:

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
    + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";

// Now you can use the document to read your elements
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

The [Jsoup Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) shows a great number of examples.

You can also use Jsoup to [sanitize](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) your data i.e. remove unwanted attributes and tags.

```
Jsoup.clean("<p>Some text</p>", Whitelist.none()); // -> "Some text"
```

Easy to setup, recommended!